# Using Command Line input CTRL+D with try catch statements

Tags: java, try-catch

I've tried to use catch(EOFException), and a couple other things, but i'm not sure how to get this to work.

Code:

```
public class Circle {      // Student Starter code
   private double radius;    // circle radius

   /**
    * Constructor - Create a new circle
    * @param    inRadius  radius of the circle
    */


   public Circle(double inRadius ) throws Exception{
       if(inRadius > 0.0)
       {
       radius = inRadius;
       }
       else
           throw new ShapeException("ShapeException occurred...");

   }

   /**
    * Return the radius of the circle
    * @return    radius of the circle
    */
   public double getRadius() {
      return radius;
   }

   /**
    * set the radius
    * @param newRadius      new radius of the circle
    */
   public void setRadius(double newRadius) throws Exception{
       if(newRadius > 0.0)
       {
       radius = newRadius;
       }
       else{
           Exception e = new Exception("ERROR: Radius < 0");
        throw e;
         }
   }

   /**
    * Compute and return the area of the circle
    * @return    the area of the circle
    */
   public double area() {
      return Math.PI * radius * radius;
   }

   /**
    * Stretches circle size by multiplying
    * the radius by the factor provided.
    * @param    factor    stretch factor
    */
   public void stretchBy(double factor) throws Exception{
       if(factor > 0.0)
       {
       radius = radius * factor;
       }
       else
           throw new Exception("ERROR: factor < 0");
   }

   /**
    * Return a string representation of a circle.
    * @return    a string representing this circle
    */
   public String toString() {
       return String.format("Circle: %s", getRadius());
   }
}
```

Tester Class:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

 public class TestCircleC{
 public static void main(String [] args) {
 // read a radius of the circle from command line 
 boolean run = true;
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

 while(run){
   try{
       System.out.printf("Enter a circle radius: ");

       String sradius = scan.next();

       if(sradius.length() <= 0){
       System.out.println("CTRL+D entered - program terminated");
       run = false;
       System.exit(0);
       }

       double radius = Double.parseDouble(sradius);
       // Instantiate a Circle object
       Circle aCircle = new Circle(radius);

       // Print current status of the circle
       System.out.println(aCircle);

       if(radius > 0){
          System.exit(0);
          run = false;
       }

    } 
    catch(EOFException eofe){
       System.out.print("CTRL+D entered - program terminated");
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException ime){
       System.out.println("InputMismatchException occurred...");
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException nse){
       System.out.println("CTRL+D entered- program terminated");
       run = false;
       System.exit(0);
    }

    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aie) {
          System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurred...");
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
       System.out.println("NumberFormatException occurred...");
    }
    catch(ShapeException se){
       System.out.println("Shape Exception Occurred... ");
       //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

 }   

}
}
```

So the code produces my output correctly so far, just trying to get it to produce the output with the CTRL+ D input doesn't want to work for some reason.

I'm not allowed to use hasNext with the scanner is the only exception to my work.

I'm collecting input through the mac terminal window and I'm looking for the output to resemble this...

```
Enter a circle radius: CTRL+D entered - program terminated
```

To do....
 1. Check if valid input, then terminate loop (x)
 2. If Code stopped by Ctrl+d output above information ()

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do in order to get the program to print that when the input to the command line terminates the program

Thanks in advance

------assignment----

Modify the program to print a promt for the input value and read in the double input value using scanner class.  do not test using hasNextInt.

Modify program to throw exceptions above

When the exception for entering the Control-D occurs, print the message "CTRL+D entered - program terminated" for all other exceptions it is sufficient to print out a message saying what kind of exception occurred.

Comment: Try using a debugger and see what happens in your code when you input EOF

Comment: When i enter EOF I get the InputMismatchException occurred.   I wasn't sure how to place the argument that if the user inputs CTRL+D (mac) in the terminal window, that it will not only terminate the code, but also provide the message "CTRL+D entered - program terminated".  I've read some areas that have looked at the trying to use the size of the input which is where I looked at trying to maybe make a finally{if(inputsize = none) print the above message}.  Would that be the right route to solving this problem?

Comment: The `InputMismatchException` is almost certainly because you used `scan.nextDouble();`. EOF isn't a `double`, right?

Comment: What you probably want is to read the next line as a `String`, check for EOF, then if it isn't parse the double and continue.

Comment: I've edited to the code to accept the string first and checks to see if the length of the string is less than zero, given it isn't then the code would have been terminated by ctrl+d and it would output the message and terminate the loop.  Sorry if I'm a little slow at getting what you're trying to say.  Based on the current edits of the code i don't believe the line length is being inputed when the program is terminated by ctrl+d, so it's returning the NoSuchElement Exception in an infinite loop, but it's also not catching the EOF exception (even after removing the if statement with the length

Comment: Based on a quick check on my machine it appears CTRL+D closes the input stream, which would cause `scanner` to output a `NoSuchElementException`, as it isn't supposed to read from a closed stream. So I'm not even sure if you can read from the console after CTRL+D was input, as `Scanner`s can't read from a closed input stream... Is EOF an error you really need to catch?

Comment: One thing you can try is inside the `catch` block for `NoSuchElementException`, test to see if your scanner is closed or not. If it's closed, then say it's an EOF.

Comment: I may just go in for office hours tomorrow morning :P.  I found Throw IllegalStateException http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html, which says throws and exception when scanner is closed.  I'm not sure what you mean by checking it within the catch block (I'm still pretty new to try/catch as it is.

Comment: That's always a good idea. If you press CTRL+D on the command line, you get a `NoSuchElementException`, right? What I *think* happens is that CTRL+D closes the `System.in` input stream that your scanner reads from, so if you get a `NoSuchElementException` *and* the scanner is closed, then the program was terminated likely through CTRL+D, so you can output the proper message.

Comment: Well, now that I just checked maybe that won't work, because you can't check whether a scanner is closed... I'm afraid anything else I suggest will be a pretty ugly solution... My apologies.

Comment: No you've been a great help :).  lol, I'm just a tiny bit stressed so I may just move onto another assignment for awhile.  My roommate said there might be a way for scanner to recognize a ctrl+d input?  When looking at other examples they used hasNext.  If you have more input I'd appreciate it, even an ugly solution is a solution haha.  I'll be around for a little bit, i would like to get some other stuff done since this is kind of just taking a lot of time to solve :P

Comment: I'll do some experimenting and let you know. `hasNext()` just tells you whether you have more input; I don't think it'll tell you what kind of input though.

Comment: OK, so the thing is that it appears that ^D is only registered at the beginning of a line... So it might be a little tricky to catch

Comment: Hmmm... Could be possible that inside your catch you can do a check for whether the scanner has a next element. If not, I guess you could assume CTRL+D... I haven't been able to get a situation where you get a NoSuchElementException without CTRL+D though, for some odd reason

Comment: Haha, I'll let you know the answer when i get it figured out tomorrow XD

Comment: All right, good luck!

Comment: >.< well maybe it was sleep deprivation lol...it was calling the correct catch NoSuchElement I just had to change the message to the CTRL+D and make it terminate the loop, and or end the program haha

Comment: Oh, interesting to hear the solution was simple after all....